# force blazegraph to listen on localhost only

Tags: localhost, restriction, blazegraph

The blazegraph.jar contains an older Jetty server that triggers security warnings. Is there a way to force blazegraph to only listen to port 9999 on localhost and not on the general network interface 0.0.0.0? I tried the -Djetty.host=127.0.0.1 but that didn't have any effect (e.g., still accessible from a remote computer).

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#quickstart-config-what has some jetty config info